# Datadog Dashboard Query for JSON Services

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I am trying to create a `TopList` visualization or alternatively a `Query` to view all services ingesting logs that are not in JSON format.

I am able to find all services ingesting logs in any format using:

`sum:datadog.estimated_usage.logs.ingested_events{*,*,$service,$datadog_index} by {service}.as_count()`

Will be great if I can trim this down to those ingesting non json logs.